# Zend Framework 2 formLabel translation

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm working on a project using Zend Framework 2. Right now I'am running into a problem while trying to translate the form labels in my view. In general the translation via MvcTranslator is working for every element using $this->translate('foo'). But as off right now, the form label they as they where defined.

This is my setup atm (shortend):

module/App/config/module.config.php (Config)

```
'service_manager'                   => array(
    'aliases'                       => array(
        'translator'                => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator'                        => array(
    'locale'                        => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns'     => array(
        array(
            'type'                  => 'gettext',
            'base_dir'              => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'               => '%s.mo',
            'text_domain'           => __NAMESPACE__,
        ),
    ),
),
```

module/App/Foo/Form/BarForm.php (Form)

```
     $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'bar',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Bar',
        ),
    ));
```

module/App/Foo/view/foo/index/index.phtml (View)

```
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formLabel($form->get('bar'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

I manually added the translation for 'bar' to my language files using Poedit, but the label will not be translated.

=== What I tried so far ===

Besides making sure, that everything is set up the right way, I tried the following things:

If I use

```
$this->translate('Bar')
```

in my view script, the value will be translated, with any problems.

I tried to set the TextDomain for the formLabel using

```
$this->formLabel()->setTranslatorTextDomain(__NAMESPACE__);
```

which doesn't change anything.

I checked if the translator is available in the view and it is. As a side note, I am also using Zend\Navigation an all element are there will be translated using

```
$this->navigation('navigation')->setTranslatorTextDomain(__NAMESPACE__);
```

Am I missing something? I'm really stuck on this one and would appreciate any suggestions. Also if you need more code or have further questions, just let me know :)

Thank you

Comment: I now tried the whole setup in a new module and I'm still not getting it to work. I'm thankful for any suggestions

Comment: Sorry to pick this old thread up again. But maybe someone has an idea now

Comment: Did you solved this ?